# Closing file in Python without having an explicit variable associated with it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. Somebody help me please.
I have opened a file like this

```
files = {'file' : open(jsonfile, 'r')}
```

How to close the file?

Comment: `files.get('file').close()`

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you do `introspection` before closing the file by  checking its [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

```
>>> files = {'file_1': open('abc.txt', 'w')}
>>> if isinstance(files.get('file_1'), file):
...     files.get('file_1').close()
... 
>>> files.get('file_1')
<closed file 'abc.txt', mode 'w' at 0x90f16a8>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   f = open(jsonfile, 'r')
   files = {'file' : f}
   f.close()
```